# How to return to certain component of navigation stack when clicking on it from a bottom tab navigator

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

My React Native app has this structure:

- Bottom Tabs Navigator

  - Stack Navigator 1

    - Screen A
    - Screen B
  - Stack Navigator 2

So I click on Stack Navigator 1 from the bottom tab navigator and go to Screen A, to Screen B, then close it. When I click Stack Navigator 1 again, Screen B shows up. What is the best way to "reset" it so every time I open Stack Navigator 1, Screen A shows up?

The current code in the Bottom Tabs Navigator:

```
<Tab.Navigator>
   <Tab.Screen
      name="Stack"
      component={StackNavigator1}
   />
   <Tab.Screen
      name="Other"
      component={Other}
   />
/>
```

Making Screen A the initial route of StackNavigator does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `navigate("ScreenA")` to whatever closes Screen B. For instance, if Screen B is closed by a button:

```
onPress={() => {
   props.navigation.navigate("ScreenA");
   props.navigation.navigate("Home");
}}
```

The user will not see Screen A, but the stack will open on Screen A next time it is opened.